# Tkinter : How to print cursor coordinations on screen forever

Tags: python, tkinter

`<Motion>` won't work when hovering on another window. So I need an infinite loop, but I can't access event attribute without `bind()` the `method(event)`.

```
def method(event):
   x = event.x
   y = event.y
   print(x.y)
root.bind("<Motion>",method)
```

I can't find any other event to trigger continuously the method. Also, I don't know how to access event attribute outside `bind()` method.

Comment: By "another window" do you mean a window not managed by tk? Tkinter can only process events on its own windows.

Comment: First off, on the 4th line, you need to add a comma, not period. 

```print(x, y)``` not ```print(x.y)```.  Can you please be more specific in your question? Please tell us the expected output, and what your output is. Thanks!

Comment: Try `root.winfo_pointerxy()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `winfo_pointerxy()` to get the current mouse position and then use `after()` to show the mouse position continuously:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

mpos = tk.Label(root, font=(None,24), width=20, height=5)
mpos.pack()

def show_mouse_pos(last=None):
    xy = root.winfo_pointerxy()
    if xy != last:
        mpos.config(text=str(xy))
        last = xy
    root.after(100, show_mouse_pos, xy)

show_mouse_pos()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: how do you know xy argument in after() can pass to show_mouse_pos()?
is it convention?

Comment: Any arguments after the function callback will be passed to the callback as arguments.